# Add an alias to a schema object in OpenLdap

Tags: openldap

Is it possible to add an alias to a schema atrribute type in openldap? Could anyone provide the command line instruction to accomplish this?

For example,

```
Description RFC2256: Telephone Number
OID 2.5.4.20
Obsolete    No
Inherits from   
Equality    telephoneNumberMatch
Ordering    (not specified)
Substring Rule  telephoneNumberSubstringsMatch
Syntax  Telephone Number (1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.50)
Single Valued   No
Collective  No
User Modification   Yes
Usage   (not specified)
Maximum Length  32 characters
Aliases (none)
Used by objectClasses   dmd documentSeries domain organization            organizationalPerson organizationalRole organizationalUnit person    residentialPerson RFC822localPart room
Force as MAY by config  No
```

I want to update the Aliases from none to "Test1"

Comment: LSS, Because I cannot change the server side configuration of a voip provider. So It needs to be aliased.

Answer (score 2):

You need to locate the scheme entry in one of the files in the `schemas` directory and add the alias there. You'll find other examples in those files of what an alias looks like. Then just restart the server.

Comment: Very vague. Precise instructions required. I have located the schema attribute for telephoneNumber. Adding the alias looks like this: attributetype ( 2.5.4.20 NAME ( 'telephoneNumber' 'telephone' )
 DESC 'RFC2256: Telephone Number'
 EQUALITY telephoneNumberMatch
 SUBSTR telephoneNumberSubstringsMatch
 SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.50{32}
 USAGE userApplications
)   However, rebooting the server does not read this file or make any changes to the existing schema.

Comment: Hmm, you might also need to run slapindex to propagate the schema change. I'll look into this some more but it's difficult with a wrist in plaster :-|

Comment: I think I'm setup using online configuration. http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/slapd-config.html

Comment: That doesn't change anything I've said here.